# pthreads, how do I use the different types?

Tags: c, pthreads

I am trying to debug some mutex errors, and I read this: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_mutex_lock.html

There is some different kinds of types listed, like PTHREAD_MUTEX_ERRORCHECK etc. How do I initalize a mutex with that type?

I have used this line to initalize a mutex before:

```
pthreads_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To stay POSIX compliant use [`pthread_mutexattr_settype()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutexattr_gettype.html).

On GNUish systems just do

```
pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_ERRORCHECK_MUTEX_INITIALIZER_NP;
```

---

Also please not that the link you quote in your question refers to "Issue 6" which is outdated, the current version is ["Issue 7"](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutex_lock.html).